# Chrome tabs flicker and appear blank

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, chrome-for-android, lineageos

I'm using chrome 106 on Lenovo tb3-710i android 6.0.1 LineageOS custom rom. Chrome tabs at the top flicker constantly and appear in a white blank block shape. How can I solve this problem?

[image: picture of tabs strange shape]

Comment: Could be a bug of chrome or of the ROM (graphics driver). Try different versions of Chrome and check if they show the same behavior.

Comment: @Robert Thank you. I actually remember that this didn't happen till chrome updated to version 106. I installed chrome 94 for android 5 (I had it before installing LineageOS) and it returned back to normal! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by installing an older version of chrome (version 94) that's made for android 5. It was my android version before switching to LineageOS. 
I also went to chrome app in google play and unchecked "enable auto update" from the three dots at the top so that it doesn't update by itself.